# Vector triple product under integral

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Assume $ \vec{r}' \perp d\vec{l} $, and $ \vec{B} = \mathrm{const} $ (constant vector field).

How to prove the identity:
\begin{equation*}
\oint\limits_L  \vec{r}'\times( d\vec{l} \times \vec{B}) = - \vec{B} \times  \frac12 \oint\limits_L  \left( \vec{r}'\times d\vec{l}\right)   
\end{equation*}
where $L$ is a  closed loop.

How to take out a constant vector from this kind of integral?
(I don't understand where the factor 1/2 comes from, but the formula is right).

Comment: It could be helpful if you provided a reference for this identity.

Comment: @EricAngle II changed the question a little.

Answer (score 0):

By the expansion formula and $dl\cdot r =0$

$$ \int r\times (dl \times B ) =  \int B \cdot r \  dl  -  B \int r \cdot dl   = \int B \cdot r \  dl $$

and

$$-B\times \int r\times dl = -\int r\  B\cdot dl + \int B \cdot r \ dl  $$

Comment: Where's the 1/2 factor? I know how to apply the bac-cab formula.....

Comment: Thats fine, but your  question was how to get the constant out of the integral.  Why the first integral  should equal the second needs additional information. I think.

Comment: I need the end result. I've already twisted a lot of formulas, and I know one implicit way to get this result. By the way, 1/2 r' x dl is the area of the loop.